# Is it legal to promote a pointer to a place that wasn't defined?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void g(int* p, int* q)
{
    *(p + *q) = 2*(*q);
    q++;
}

int main()
{
    int a[6];
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        g(a,&i);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it legal to promote a pointer to a place that wasn't defined?

I mean in function `g`: the code `q++;`. Is it legal?

Comment: I don't see anything "illegal" in this code. BTW `q++` does not promote anything, it just increments q. There is nothing that "wasn't defined" hwere.

Comment: That's incrementation, not promotion, and `q` is defined within the function. What's the problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to ask? btw, why are doing `q++`?

Comment: Becareful if you use *q after you risk a seg fault error

Comment: I wanted to see if something will go wrong if I add 1 to the adress of 'i'.. but it did't affect. I thought it's not legal because i is integer, not an array.

Comment: In langage C you can do what you want with memory but if you access memory of other program for example OS should stop programm in theory

Comment: @user1980750 Pointers to memory arithmetic is legal in C.. but you can't know for sure what will happen if you try to access that memory.

Comment: Compiler may optimize out the _pointless_ pointer increment.

Answer (score 2):

It is always well-defined to treat a single object as an array of 1 element.
Thus, if you have:

```
int i= 0; int* q= &i; q++ /* incrementing once is well-defined */
```

it is well-defined to increment q exactly once. Increment q more than once, and you have undefined behavior. That is, your C implementation may do whatever it wants with your code. It could print an error (some compilers can detect this sort of thing in simple cases) , or it could produce code that silently misbehaves, or it could produce a segfault.

Furthermore, after you increment q exactly once, it becomes a past-the-end pointer. There are only three well-defined things you can do with a past-the-end pointer; you can compare it with another pointer to the same array, you can decrement it, and you can copy it. If you access the object pointed to by a past-the-end pointer, you get undefined behavior.

In your example, nothing is done with q after it is incremented; the function merely returns, and q disappears. Next time it is called, q is initialized with a valid value, and again, only incremented once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "Is it legal in C to point pointers to whatever arbitrary address I choose?", then the answer is, "Yes, it's legal C. The compiler won't stop you from doing it?"

It is, however, very unsafe. Like @user43968 wrote in his/her comment, you're risking a segfault if you're not careful (probably risking it even if you are careful).

Answer (score 0):

In your code all that `q++` does is increment a pointer

In the context of the program this particular line has no effect, `q` isn't returned from the function and isn't used after this in the function

As user43968 says in the comments, after this increment `q` is pointing to an undefined location and may cause an error if you modify the program to use it